# My webpage body are wider then the content.

Tags: css, width

I did notice the other questions about this topic but none of them gave me an answer. I've checked everything, and i can't seem to figure it out. Am going crazy... Anyhow, any and all help would be appreciated!

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;

}

body {
    font-family: Merriweather,'Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
}

hr {
    max-width: 50px;
    border-color: #f05f40;
    border-width: 3px;
}

hr.light {
    border-color: #f05f40;
}

a {
    color: #f05f40;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: #eb3812;
}

h1,

h3 {color: white;}
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
}

p {
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.bg-primary {
    background-color: black;
    color: black;
    background-image: url();
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    min-height: 250px;
    border: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
}

.bg-dark {
    color: white;
    background-color: #222;
}

.black_overlay{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        z-index:1001;
        -moz-opacity: 0.8;
        opacity:.80;
        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    }
    .white_content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: -5px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 122.5%;
        padding: 16px;
        border: 5px solid white;
        background-color: black;
        z-index:1002;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .white_content p {
    top: 
    }

.text-faded {
    color: white;
}

.black_overlay2{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        z-index:1001;
        -moz-opacity: 0.8;
        opacity:.80;
        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    }
    .white_content2 {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: -5px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 122.5%;
        padding: 16px;
        border: 5px solid white;
        background-color: black;
        z-index:1002;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .white_content2 p {
    top: 
    }

.text-faded2 {
    color: white;
}

section {
    padding: 100px 0;
}

aside {
    padding: 50px 0;
}

.no-padding {
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-default {
    border-color: black;
    font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #f05f40;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #eb3812;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li>a,
.navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus:hover {
    color: white;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li.active>a,
.navbar-default .nav>li.active>a:focus {
    color: #f05f40!important;
    background-color: white;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav>li.active>a:focus:hover {
    background-color: white;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .navbar-default {
        border-color: white;
        background-color: black;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
        color: #f05f40;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .navbar-default .nav > li>a,
    .navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus {
        color: white;
    }

    .navbar-default .nav > li>a:hover,
    .navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus:hover {
        color: #f05f40;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix {
        border-color: white;
        background-color: black;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #f05f40;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
    .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
        color: #f05f40;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix .nav > li>a,
    .navbar-default.affix .nav>li>a:focus {
        color:#f05f40;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix .nav > li>a:hover,
    .navbar-default.affix .nav>li>a:focus:hover {
        color: white;
    }
}

header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/KoxvkYj.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

header .header-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 100px 15px;
    text-align: center;

}

header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;

}

header .header-content .header-content-inner hr {
    margin: 30px auto;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner p {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);

}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    header {
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    header .header-content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        padding: 0 50px;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    header .header-content .header-content-inner {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }

    header .header-content .header-content-inner p {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        max-width: 80%;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
.container {
    color: white;
    background-image: url();
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    min-height: auto;


}
.container h5 {
    color: white;
margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 40px;}
.container2 {
    color: #f05f40;
    background-image: url();
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    min-height: 250px;
   border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: white;

}
#contact3 {
    color: white;
    background-image: url("http://www.datalicious.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/img1.jpg");
   border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: white;


}
.section-heading {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.service-box {
    background-image: url("");
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

@media(min-width:992px) {
    .service-box {
        margin: 20px auto 0;
    }
}

.service-box p {

    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.portfolio-box {
    top:50px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 650px;
    border: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    

}
.portfolio-box:hover {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 650px;
    border: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #f05f40;
    color: ;
    

}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,1,.7);
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateY(-50%);<
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-category,
.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-name {
    padding: 0 15px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-category {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-name {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.portfolio-box:hover .portfolio-box-caption {
    opacity: 1;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-category {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption .portfolio-box-caption-content .project-name {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
}

.call-to-action h2 {
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
}

.text-primary {
    color: #f05f40;
}

.no-gutter > [class*=col-] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.btn-default {
    border-color: red;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus,
.btn-default.focus,
.btn-default:active,
.btn-default.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
    border-color: #ededed;
    color: #222;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.btn-default:active,
.btn-default.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
    background-image: none;
}

.btn-default.disabled,
.btn-default[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default,
.btn-default.disabled:hover,
.btn-default[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:hover,
.btn-default.disabled:focus,
.btn-default[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:focus,
.btn-default.disabled.focus,
.btn-default[disabled].focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default.focus,
.btn-default.disabled:active,
.btn-default[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:active,
.btn-default.disabled.active,
.btn-default[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default.active {
    border-color: #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.btn-default .badge {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #222;
}

.btn-primary {
    border: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    color: #f05f40;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    border-color: #ed431f;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ee4b28;
}

.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    background-image: none;
}

.btn-primary.disabled,
.btn-primary[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary,
.btn-primary.disabled:hover,
.btn-primary[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary.disabled:focus,
.btn-primary[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.disabled.focus,
.btn-primary[disabled].focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.focus,
.btn-primary.disabled:active,
.btn-primary[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.disabled.active,
.btn-primary[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.active {
    border-color: #f05f40;
    background-color: #f05f40;
}

.btn-primary .badge {
    color: #f05f40;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.btn {
    border: 100;
    border-radius: 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.btn-xl {
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

::-moz-selection {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #222;
}

::selection {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #222;
}

img::selection {
    color: #fff;
    background: 0 0;
}

img::-moz-selection {
    color: #fff;
    background: 0 0;
}

body {
    webkit-tap-highlight-color: #222;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to get rid of the (horizontal) scrollbars? If so, try changing:

```
body {
    font-family: Merriweather,'Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

to

```
body {
        font-family: Merriweather,'Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: Almost! But this is a one page website. And when i change the overflow to hidden i can't scroll.

Comment: Try changing the aforementioned "overflow: hidden;" to "overflow-x: hidden;"

Comment: Hmm. Seems to work OK at: https://jsfiddle.net/3bnjducz/
So, you want to get rid of the horizontal scrollbars, but keep the vertical ones? Make sure the overflow is deleted, so you only have the overflow-x property :)

Comment: ah, i placed the overflow in the wrong body. but now i can't click on my nav-bar and it automatically scrolls down.. :O you fixed the scrolling issue, but started another issue xD #EverydayHTML.

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Strange, it shouldn't effect the navbar. Is the issue that the navbar won't scroll down with the page, or that the page doesn't scroll down when you click on a link in the navbar?

Comment: When i click a link in the navbar

Answer (score 0):

not seeing the issue based on your question but i do see that body size is defined with% while much of the content size is defined with px, which is fixxed while percent is based on the screen size.

Comment: Correct, but i still have that deadspace and it got nothing to do with that. This is a hard one, I've been going at it for an hour and i can't figure out what and when that happened.. But thanks!